# Continuity definition

Tags: general-topology

The definition of continuity I have always seen is that if $X,Y$ are topological spaces and $f : X \rightarrow Y$, then $f$ is continuous if for any open $B \subseteq Y$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is open in X. Wouldn't it be more natural to define it that if $A \subseteq X$ is open then $f(A)$ is open in Y?

Answer (score 2):

Consider a simple example. Let $X = \mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, and $Y = \{0,1\}$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ (so all four subsets of $Y$ are open). Let $f : X \to Y$ be given by 
$$f = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }x = 0 \\
0 & \text{if }x \neq 0 \\
\end{cases}$$
If continuity is to behave as we expect, this function should not be continuous because of the "jump" at $x=0$.

Under the actual definition, this is indeed the case: $\{1\}$ is an open subset of $Y$, but $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{0\}$ is not an open subset of $X$.

Under the proposed definition, $f$ would be continuous, because $f(U)$ is an open subset of $Y$ for any (open or not) subset $U$ of $X$.

Answer (score 1):

What you have stated is the definition of $f$ being an [*open map*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_and_closed_maps). This is (perhaps surprisingly) **not** the same as being continuous. In fact, neither one implies the other!

Comment: I suppose you could switch the definitions (and subsequently you'd probably need to change many other definitions), but then continuity in topology and continuity in analysis would not be the same.